# Rails custom validation on has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, associations

Given the following models:

Business

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  ## OWNERS / EMPLOYEES
  has_many :business_users, as: :business, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :business_users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :business_users, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: lambda { |a| a[:user_id].blank? || a[:role].blank? }
end
```

BusinessUser

```
class BusinessUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :business, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user

  enum role: {:owner => 0, :employee => 1, :admin => 2}

  validates_presence_of :user
  validates :user, uniqueness: { scope: :business, message: "Each user can only have one role" }

end
```

User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :business_users
  has_many :businesses, through: :business_users, source_type: Business, source: :business

end
```

How can i make sure that each business has at least one business_user with role :owner?

Comment: Since you would need to create your business before you can associate a business user with it, you're going to struggle to validate that a business user exists prior to saving your business object.

Comment: As a tip, you'd be best putting your `validations` into **one** call:

`validates :user, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :business, message: "Each user can only have one role" }`